# IOS -> MySql Wordpress Database?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, wordpress

I'm building an IOS app that will need to talk to a MySql database which will be shared with a  WP site.

(Essentially the APP will send data to MySql which will then be reflected on the WP site)

So I think we need a simple REST API to talk to the MySql database.. Is that correct?

Are there any established solutions out there for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want 'raw' database access, you could use dbslayer ( http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer ) - a http+json abstraction for mysql. You have to be very careful with access right though.

For really fast JSON handling you can use JSONKit https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit